# cassandra timeseries data model

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

I have seen whether station data model as timeseries in that we are storing many tempratures as multiple columns against one rowkey which is whether stationId.
https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

But now my query is - 
I need store availability (may be changed 10 times in 1 min) of millions of products.
And I will create an API which will facilitate clients to read products availability by timestamp.

So customer can ask for all the availability changed articles since timestamp (t1) and I then need to provide them..

- We can do this by putting secondary index on timestamp like -

  - create index if not exists on stocks_51 (update_sequence);
- But as i said i will have millions of products, this secondary index will be costly my cql will be 
  select * from table where update_sequence > timestamp1 - (which will be costly)

So please suggest some data model which is reliable and fast enough

Currently we dont have tables created - I want to design in better way so consulting first.
To be more specific - We need all the products whose availability has changed since some time.. time can be of any (1 month older 1yr older 5 yr older)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: your question is good but not clear. What is availibility, is it number or just 0/1 ? Do you want all the products available in a day, month,year based on availibility?

Comment: Better you give your table defination as well.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response.
OK , fine
Currently we dont have tables created - I want to design in better way so consulting

Yes We need all the products whose availability has changed since some time.. time can be of any (1 month older 1yr older 5 yr older)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the product logs, use like below data model -

```
create table product_log(
    productid int,
    changedon bigint,
    availability int, 
    primary key (productid,changedon)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (changedon DESC);
```

Insert Queries --

```
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (100,1486562259037,28);-- oldest time stamp value for changedon
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (100,1486562296492,29); 
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (200,1486562322372,30);
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (200,1486562332019,31);
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (300,1486562340851,32);
insert into product_log (productid,changedon,availability) values (300,1486562348963,33); -- latest time stamp value for changedon
```

Select * query ---

```
        cqlsh:nasa> select * from product_log;

 productid | changedon     | availability
-----------+---------------+--------------
       200 | 1486562332019 |           31
       200 | 1486562322372 |           30
       100 | 1486562296492 |           29
       100 | 1486562259037 |           28
       300 | 1486562348963 |           33
       300 | 1486562340851 |           32

(6 rows)
```

Range query based on changedon value -

```
        cqlsh:nasa> select * from product_log where changedon > 1486562259037 and changedon < 1486562348963 ALLOW FILTERING;

 productid | changedon     | availability
-----------+---------------+--------------
       200 | 1486562332019 |           31
       200 | 1486562322372 |           30
       100 | 1486562296492 |           29
       300 | 1486562340851 |           32

(4 rows)
```

Range queries on clustering columns are allowed. Only problem with this design is, it will create wide row. If you have too many updates for same product id, partition will be uneven.

Comment: hmm That i tried but as u mentioned , we will have many updates per id per day.

Comment: Can materialized view be useful here ?

Comment: Yes, if you are using c*3 .